# PARTITION BY and COUNT function not returning thesame value

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

Please I need more information on this Partition By command on Postgres.
As they don't return the same value.

Assuming this is a table

| SN | Gender |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Boy |
| 2 | Boy |
| 3 | Boy |
| 4 | Girl |

I use the count command:

```
 select name, count(name)
    from sex
    group by name
```

And I get:

| Sex | count |
| --- | --- |
| Boy | 3 |
| Girl | 1 |

But when I use the partition method:

```
select DISTINCT name,
       count(name),
       count(name) OVER (PARTITION BY name)
from sex
group by name
```

I get:

| Sex | count |
| --- | --- |
| Boy | 1 |
| Girl | 1 |

Please what am I missing??

Comment: `Gender` or `Name` ?

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between aggregate and window functions is that the former "*aggregates*" rows (output will contain less rows of the input), while the latter just "*computes a value*" for each row (output will always contain the same amount of rows of the input). As long as window functions don't aggregate, they don't have a `GROUP BY` clause, even though they use a `PARTITION BY` clause to generate these computed values for each row.

If you want to achieve the same output of the aggregate function, with a window function, you need to use only:

- the window function `COUNT`, to get the count for each of your rows,
- the `DISTINCT` keyword, to remove duplicate rows (this is applying the aggregation, since window functions can't carry out it)

```
SELECT DISTINCT gender,
                COUNT(gender) OVER (PARTITION BY gender) AS cnt
FROM sex
```

Try removing the `DISTINCT` keyword and observing the output as well.